# Extracting just one element from Date variable

Tags: r, date

The date is currently in year/Month format. For example, 2010/Aug. I am trying to extract just the month to be a factor. When I use 
`Date=as.POSIXct(Date)`, it says `NA NA NA` in the data.

Comment: Try `factor(sub(".*/", "", Date))`

Comment: I wonder if your date as "2010/Aug" is actually a string, and not in a datetime format.

Comment: I am a beginner so please bear with me... when I do "factor(sub("Aug*/", "Month", Date))" it says "factor(0) Levels: ". How do I make it pull just the months? Thanks.

Comment: I think it should be `factor(sub(".*/", "", "2010/Aug"))`